# Panel Layout Designer

Tags: 7, panels

I came across [this video](http://www.drupalove.com/drupal-video/creating-custom-page-using-panels-1) showing how to setup custom home page using Panels. I installed the [Chaos tool suite](http://drupal.org/project/ctools), and [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) modules, but I don't see the Layout designer interface anywhere as it is shown in the video.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Administer › Site building › Pages for the page you are wanting to design.

Click on the Content link in the left column and you should see a button for 'Show Layout Designer'.

Answer (score 2):

I found it - well sort of. In my Main panel menu, once you have created a page and chosen custom layout,under the list of pages, there is a manga custom layout option. This takes you to a page that looks like the layout designer they were talking about.